# How to check if the first letter in VARCHAR is always an alphabet

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar

I am new to sql and while creating my table, is there a way in which I can check/ enforce that the first letter is always an alphabet? Eg. `<alphabet><numbers>`

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING
(
    TestID VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT TestPK PRIMARY KEY (TestID)
);
```

When inserting new data into the `TESTING` table, it should be `T12345` and prompts an error if the input is `12345` for example?

I have a couple of tables in which each of them have its own ID (of 6 digits) and hence, I thought it will be easier to gave them a prefix of an alphabet (eg. if it is a Customer table, it will be C etc) so that I can visualize my tables/ content in a clearer manner...
Thus the datatype used is VARCHAR as it is an alphanumeric value as opposed to INT which I used initially.

Comment: "I have a couple of tables in which each of them have its own ID (of 6 digits) and hence, I thought it will be easier to gave them a prefix of an alphabet (eg. if it is a Customer table, it will be C etc) so that I can visualize my tables/ content in a clearer manner" .... Don't. Just use the integer. If you want to visualise it easier then when you **DISPLAY** the data then prefix a `C` (or whatever character you want) but don't add an otherwise redundant character and change your data type just to change how it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE()` to add a constraint for `TestID`:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING
(
    TestID VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT TestPK PRIMARY KEY (TestID),
    CONSTRAINT first_letter CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(TestID, '^[A-Za-z]'))
);
```

If you want the 1st char to be an upper case letter, then it's simpler:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING
(
    TestID VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT TestPK PRIMARY KEY (TestID),
    CONSTRAINT first_letter CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(TestID, '^[A-Z]'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a couple of tables in which each of them have its own ID (of 6 digits) and hence, I thought it will be easier to gave them a prefix of an alphabet (eg. if it is a Customer table, it will be C etc) so that I can visualize my tables/ content in a clearer manner.

As a frame challenge, you would be better to not use this approach and keep the `ID` as an `NUMBER` data type and then if you want a prefix then to add it when the value is displayed:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    ID NUMBER(6,0) CONSTRAINT customer_id_pk PRIMARY KEY
);
```

If you have the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO customer ( id )
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, when you want to **DISPLAY** the data then format it with the prefix:

```sql
SELECT 'C' || TO_CHAR( id, 'FM000000' ) AS id
FROM   customer;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | ID      |
> | :------ |
> | C000001 |
> | C123456 |
> ```

If you want you could add it as a generated column to the table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer ADD (
  FORMATTED_ID VARCHAR2(7)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 'C' || CAST( TO_CHAR( id, 'FM000000' ) AS VARCHAR(6) ) )
);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customer;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>     ID | FORMATTED_ID
> -----: | :-----------
>      1 | C000001     
> 123456 | C123456
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03f7a82c32cd4214c223558efa2fbc95)*

Answer (score 0):

This is to add to MTOs answer.  I don't think what you want to do is even necessary.  The number is fine.  Why?

You have chosen a good naming convention for your columns -- `<entity name>ID`.  So, when you look at the results of a query, you'll have a column `TestID`.  That is the id from the `Test` table.

Problem solved with a naming convention you are already using.